# filter data frame based on new data frame

Tags: r

Here is some toy data

```
x <- c("Bird","Bird","Tiger","Bird","Fish","grey","blue","orange","green","yellow","10","5","7","12","5","10","10","8","12","2","10","20","10","18","3")
m <- matrix(x,byrow = F,ncol = 5,nrow= 5)
m <- as.data.frame(m)
colnames(m) <- c("Animal","colour","length","height","weight")

y <- c("Tiger","Bird","Bird","colour","length","colour","orange","10","green","orange/black","12","light green")
new.m <- matrix(y,byrow=F,ncol=4,nrow = 3)
new.m <- as.data.frame(new.m)
colnames(new.m) <- c("Animal","attribute","value","new value")
```

How can I efficiently update the values in `m` using the data frame `new.m`. The final result should look like this:

```
z <- c("Bird","Bird","Tiger","Bird","Fish","grey","blue","orange/black"," light green","yellow","12","5","7","12","5","10","10","8","12","2","10","20","10","18","3")
update.m <- matrix(z,byrow = F,ncol = 5,nrow= 5)
update.m <- as.data.frame(update.m)
colnames(update.m) <- c("Animal","colour","length","height","weight")
```

For a fixed row in new.m I can achieve this easily. But can this be done in comprehensive not row based way?

Comment: Do also want to test the old value? (Does the value mentioned in `new.m` exists in `m`? What to do if there is another value?)

Comment: @jogo the values in new.m should exist in m. If there is no selection / other value it should not be replaced. Let's say in `new.m` is a row `c("Tiger, colour, green, orange/black)`. Then the Tiger row in `m` should stay as it is.

Comment: What is with more than one match for the old value?

Comment: @jogo they should all be replaced. If there is another Tiger (with different height) the colour should be changed too. Logically its: If Animal's Attribute = Value change it to new Value.

Comment: But a Tiger with a different color should not be changed?

Comment: @MikeH correct. If the animal doesnt satisfy the Attribute = Value, we will not change the attribute to the new value.

Answer (score 3):

One idea via base R. We first create a matrix with the columns we need to update the values. We use `match` to update the values. The `nomath` entries result to `NA` which we `replace` with original values and put them back in the original data frame.

```
m3 <- sapply(m[c(2:3)], function(i) new.m$`new value`[match(i, new.m$value)])
m[c(2:3)] <- replace(m3, is.na(m3), m[c(2,3)][which(is.na(m3), arr.ind = TRUE)])

m
#  Animal       colour length height weight
#1   Bird         grey     12     10     10
#2   Bird         blue      5     10     20
#3  Tiger orange/black      7      8     10
#4   Bird  light green     12     12     18
#5   Fish       yellow      5      2      3
```

Comment: thx for the anwser. Sapply is essentially the same as looping through the rows. I was wondering if you can do it in a more comprehensive way

Comment: Where is your code? You say you can achieve it easily...where is it then? And what do you mean comprehensive?? Readable? Efficient?

Comment: A loop is probably the best way since what you basically want is to do several different merges (one for each type `attribute` in `new.m`). I played around with a combination of `dcast`/`melt`/`merge` but I don't think it's dynamic since you lose some information.